# How do I make objects move independently? (Java)

Tags: java, multithreading, object, graphics, jframe

How is an object is supposed to move on it's own? My project below is the current code for a simple Ping Pong game remake. I've succeeded in getting the left Paddle to move via user input, but I do not know how to program the Ball object and AI Paddle object to move independently. I suspect that I require a multitude of Threads, but where do I place them and how can I update my objects from within the Thread?

Perhaps I misplaced the Ball and Paddle objects into the wrong class?

**Main Class:**

```
package com.N00744323.pingpong;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Display 
{   
    static JFrame frame;
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        frame = new JFrame("Ping Pong");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.getContentPane().add(new GUI());

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

**GUI frame class:**

```
package com.N00744323.pingpong;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class GUI extends JPanel
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    final private int WIDTH = 750, HEIGHT = 500;

    private Paddle p1, p2;
    private Ball b;

    public GUI()
    {   
        addKeyListener(new DirectionListener());
        p1 = new Paddle(1);
        p2 = new Paddle(2);
        b = new Ball();
        setBackground(Color.black);

        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
        setFocusable(true);
    }

    public int getWIDTH()
    {
        return WIDTH;
    }
    public int getHEIGHT()
    {
        return HEIGHT;
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics page)
    {
        super.paintComponent(page);

        page.setColor(Color.black);
        page.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

        page.setColor(Color.white);
        page.fillRect(p1.getLocX(), p1.getLocY(), p1.getWIDTH(), p1.getHEIGHT());
        page.fillRect(p2.getLocX(), p2.getLocY(), p2.getWIDTH(), p2.getHEIGHT());

        page.fillOval(b.getLoc()[0], b.getLoc()[1], b.getSIZE()*2, b.getSIZE()*2);
    }

    private class DirectionListener implements KeyListener
    {
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) 
        {
            int key = e.getKeyCode();
            if(key == (KeyEvent.VK_UP))
            {
                p1.setLocY(-3);
                System.out.println("Up!");
            }
            else    
                if(key == (KeyEvent.VK_DOWN))
                {
                    p1.setLocY(3);
                    System.out.println("Down!");
                }
            repaint();
        }

        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) 
        {
            int key = e.getKeyCode();

            if(key == (KeyEvent.VK_UP))
            {
                System.out.println("Up stopped!");
            }
            else    
                if(key == (KeyEvent.VK_DOWN))
                {
                    System.out.println("Down stopped!");
                }
        }

        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) 
        {
            int key = e.getKeyCode();

            if(key == (KeyEvent.VK_UP))
            {
                p1.setLocY(-2);
                System.out.println("Up!");
            }
            else    
                if(key == (KeyEvent.VK_DOWN))
                {
                    p1.setLocY(2);
                    System.out.println("Down!");
                }

            repaint();
        }
    }
}
```

**Paddle object class:**

```
package com.N00744323.pingpong;

public class Paddle
{
    final private int WIDTH = 10, HEIGHT = 45;
    private int locY, locX;

    public Paddle(int player)
    {
        if(player == 1)
        {
            locY = (500/2) - HEIGHT;
            locX = 20;
        }
        if(player == 2)
        {
            locY = (500/2) - HEIGHT;
            locX = 750-WIDTH-20;
        }
    }

    public void setLocY(int locY)
    {
        if(locY + this.locY >= 0 && this.locY + locY <= 500 - HEIGHT)
            this.locY += locY;
    }

    public int getLocY()
    {
        return locY;
    }

    public int getLocX()
    {
        return locX;
    }

    public int getWIDTH()
    {
        return WIDTH;
    }

    public int getHEIGHT()
    {
        return HEIGHT;
    }
}
```

**Ball object class:**

```
package com.N00744323.pingpong;

public class Ball
{
    final private int SIZE = 5;
    private int x, y;

    public Ball()
    {
        x = (750/2) - SIZE*2;
        y = (500/2) - SIZE*2;
    }

    public int getSIZE()
    {
        return SIZE;
    }

    public int[] getLoc()
    {
        int[] pos = {x, y};
        return pos;
    }

    public void setLoc(int[] pos)
    {
        x = pos[0];
        y = pos[1];
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I appreciate that you threw that suggestion out here, but what am I supposed to do with it? Where do I place it? What objects, if any, do I have act on it?

Comment: Last time I wrote code to move a ball on a screen, Java had not yet been invented.  But anyway, You move the paddle in response to user input by handling "key" events.  You want the ball to move in response to the passage of time.  Sounds like you might want to write a handler for some kind of timer event.  That's all I know.

Comment: what you need is a game loop, create new thread with run method that updates state of game objects and invokes repaint of GUI, all that in infinite loop.

Comment: @kamil, If you're going to tell a noob to create a new thread that's going to interact with Swing, then you probably also should tell 'em about `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`.  Andrew, Most Swing methods can only be called in Swing's Event Dispatch Thread (EDT).  invokeLater(Runnable r) is how other threads can cause functions to be called in the EDT.